# jQuery append element if it doesn't exist, otherwise replace

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a short piece of code:

```
var $el = $("#something").find(".test");
if (!$el.length) {
    $("#something").append('<div class="test">somecontent</div>');
} else {
    $el.replaceWith('<div class="test">somenewcontent</div>');
}
```

I couldn't find a method appendOrReplaceWith or anything similar.

Any ideas how can I make it shorter?

I believe that:

```
$("#something").appendOrReplace('<div class="test">sometext</div>');
```

would be much easier to read, but no such method is available yet.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Life isn't about codegolf - it's about quality.

Comment: @RUJordan quality != readability

Answer (score 5):

Just remove it first then append.

```
$(".test").remove();
$("#something").append('<div class="test">somecontent</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Mandatory vanilla answer. It may not be shorter, but it's faster.

Get the element, grab all subelements with the class "test", create your div, check the subelements length, and if length is truthy, set the `innerHTML` to the div. Else, append it.

```
var el = document.getElementById("something");
var subel = el.getElementsByClassName("test");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "test"
if (subel.length) {
    div.textContent = "somenewcontent";
    while(el.hasChildNodes()) el.removeChild(el.lastChild); //remove child nodes
    el.appendChild(div);
} else { 
    div.textContent = "somecontent";
    el.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: "Any ideas how can I make it shorter?"

Comment: @f00bar shorter is not always better.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan icwutudidthere :O

Comment: @f00bar I never said your answer was bad. I just like to advocate pure JS on jQuery questions -- I can't tell you how many times I've seen jQuery answers when all I wanted was a JS answer.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan still agree .. giving you +1 because I did not satisfy the question apparently `:/`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a method like `findOrAppend` to jQuery could be useful:

```
$.fn.findOrAppend = function(selector, content) {
    var elements = this.find(selector);
    return elements.length ? elements : $(content).appendTo(this);
}
```

Then you can chain `text`, `replaceWith`, `empty` etc. as needed:

```
$("#something")
    .findOrAppend(".test", "<div class='test'>")
    .text("newcontent");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
var $s = $("#something"), $t = $s.find(".test"), c = 'New content';
( $t[0] ? $t:$s)[( $t[0] ? 'html':'append')](( $t[0] ? c :$('<div>',{class:'test'}).append(c)));
```

Comment: (+1) Or even shorter `[!$el[0]?'append':'html']`

Comment: I don't know how readable it is, not sure I'd use it, but I like it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's perfectly readable if you know about the Conditional Operator (which is elementary in JS) so yes. +1

Comment: This is incorrect, you will replace the whole content with the html method, I want to replace only the div with class test.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I believe I may dimly recall having seen the ternary conditional operator once or twice. I love code that does conventional things in unconventional ways, but I try to avoid using it in production code. By "readable" I don't just mean "human-parsable", I mean "immediately obvious". The more obvious the intent, the easier it is to recognize how it's broken -- or that it isn't broken, and move on to the next thing. Ever dealt with a bug in a deeply nested ternary macro in C? Written by somebody who thought he knew the operator precedence rules well enough not to use parens?

Comment: @EdPlunkett While agreeing... but all the people about to be hired on a JS project should know elementary JS. `(:?)` is one of them and yes, booleans like `bool`, `!bool` or `!!bool`. So something like `return bool ? 'ok' : 'no'` should be human-parsable in an eyeblitz!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan for the record. I'd fail the code in this answer in a code review. Also, I'd fail op's code, OP has an xy problem.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum not sure to understand what you've written in your comment :|

Comment: That the fact a code is understandable doesn't mean it's good. The 'obvious' solution take a lot less time to understand.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `return bool ? 'ok' : 'no'` is a common idiom, and I agree, anybody who needs to stop and think about it is a n00b at best. But I don't expect to see ternaries between square brackets to decide which function to call. I had to stop and think. As I said, that's exactly what's fun about it. But that's also what makes it a less than ideal choice for production code. But I've had moments of weakness where I've written too-clever code. LINQ is a constant temptation.

Comment: @emilos updated but one might wear sunglasses before reading it `Bp`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should cache your selectors:

```
var $som = $('#something');
var $ele = $(".test",$som);
var newHtml = '<div class="test">somecontent</div>';

if (!$el[0]) $som.append( newHtml );
else         $ele.replaceWith( newHtml );
```

but you already did it really fine, (beside not caching repeated selectors), and me, trying to make it *smaller* could be a**-kicked for not using `{}` for my `if` and `else` :)